# How do I change the image on a JButton when clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
    JButton lunarButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("assets/Buttons/moon.png"));
    lunarButton.setActionCommand("switch");
    c.gridwidth=1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    searchArea.add(lunarButton, c);
```

.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
{
    int count = 1;
    String action = ev.getActionCommand();

    if("switch".equals(action))
    {           
        ImageIcon sun = new ImageIcon("assets/sun.png");
        ImageIcon moon = new ImageIcon("assets/moon.png");

        changeLunar();
        count++;
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
             lunarButton.setIcon(sun);
        }
        else
        {
             lunarButton.setIcon(moon);
        }
```

I have this code implemented, but eclipse tells me "lunarButton cannot be resolved", is it not able to see the lunarButton variable in my init() method? what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have `lunarButton` as an instance variable of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lunarButton may be declared locally, perhaps in the init method.

One solution: declare it as an instance field in the class, not in the init method.

Solution two: don't even worry about the variable. Get the JButton ***object*** from the ActionEvent parameter's `getSource()` method. Cast the object returned to JButton, and call whatever methods you'd like on it.

For example:

```
if("switch".equals(action))
{           
    // ImageIcon sun = new ImageIcon("assets/sun.png");
    // ImageIcon moon = new ImageIcon("assets/moon.png");

    JButton btn = (JButton) ae.getSource();

    changeLunar();
    count++;
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
         btn.setIcon(sun);
    }
    else
    {
         btn.setIcon(moon);
    }
```

As an aside: you really don't want to re-load the images from disk each time the button is pushed. Instead read the images in ***once***, perhaps in a constructor, stuff them into an ImageIcon field, and use that field when needed.

Comment: I made it as an instance field, like you said, and it worked thanks, I'll keep your other methods in mind =). I'll check when it lets me